# How to get all links on a web page using python and selenium IDE

Tags: python, css, selenium

I want to get all link from a web page using selenium  ide and python.

For example if I search test or anything on google website and I want all link related to that.

**Here is my code**

```
 from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
baseurl="https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(baseurl)
driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys("test") 
link_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='rso']/div[2]/li[2]/div/h3/a")
print link_name
driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7f0ba50c2090>
```

Using xpath `$x(".//*[@id='rso']/div[2]/li[2]/div/h3/a")` in Firebug's console.

**Output**
    [a jtypes2.asp]

How can I get links content from a object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
baseurl="https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(baseurl)
driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys("test")
driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
link_name=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='rso']/div/li/div/h3/a")
for link in link_name:
    print link.get_attribute('href')
```

Try the above code. Your code doesn't send a RETURN key after giving the search keyword. Also I've made changes to implicitly wait for 2 seconds to load the search results and I've changed xpath to get all links.

Comment: I have already tried this but it gives error.I want to clear that I need url which is present in xpath. Error   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selenium_python.py", line 14, in <module>
    a=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='rso']/div[2]/li[1]/div/h3/a")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 232, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote

Comment: Thanks It works but I need also those links which available on 2,3,4...... pages at end of the main page where we search test on google.

Comment: xpath for click next(button) page $x('.//*[@id=\'pnnext\']/span[2]'). How many times next button should be clicked